# Use Azure AD B2C to validate Facebook token

Tags: facebook, azure, active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Azure AD B2C to authenticate users coming from my web site authenticated by username and password, my website backend uses Azure Graph API to communicate with Azure AD B2C. I'd like to add Facebook Login on my website and I'd use Azure AD B2C to validate the Facebook token, is it possible? can I invoke Azure AD Graph API to validate Facebook token? how? I'm using Azure AD Graph API because I like to use my custom login/registration page.

Comment: You could add Facebook as an identity provider in the Azure AD B2C. For the details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-fb-app).

Comment: Thank you, the reported link is the guide to add facebook as Identity Provider for login workflow handled by AD. I don't want to use the workflow provided by AD (neither the login page provided by AD), I want to use AD throught Graph API to validate facebook token. Is it possible?